# How to add destination page URL in create user wizard button?

Tags: asp.net, .net, createuserwizard

I am trying to customize the create user Wizard control in asp. What it does is redirecting me to a continue page after creating the user, but I want a custom page to be displayed after creating a page.... What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle [CreatedUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.createduser.aspx) event and then `Response.Redirect()`

or play with control's [properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard_properties.aspx):

> ContinueDestinationPageUrl Gets or sets the URL of the page that the user will see after clicking the Continue button on the success page.
>
> FinishDestinationPageUrl   Gets or sets the URL that the user is redirected to when they click the Finish button.